# parse json in html page with python

Tags: python, html, json

The source code of html page is show as below

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=gb2312">
<script>
    document.domain = "xxxx.com";
    var jsonObj = {
        list: [
            {ip: "166.255.255.25", port: 1080, path: "/data/pps.jpeg"}
        ]
    }
    var jsParObj = {param1: 25532, param2: 54463}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to extract the data from that html page and store them in json format.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
script_text = soup.find('script')
```

Using python library BeautifulSoup4, I get this

```
<script>
    document.domain = "xxxx.com";
    var jsonObj = {
        list: [
            {ip: "166.255.255.25", port: 1080, path: "/data/pps.jpeg"}
        ]
    }
    var jsParObj = {param1: 25532, param2: 54463}
</script>
```

How can I remove the `<script>` tag and translate that data into json format?
Also, I use python.

Comment: I'd just search for the substring starting after regexp `jsonObj[ \t]+=`, and parse the largest JSON out of it. This approach is not really reliable, though

Comment: It is *not* json. It is just javascript, @SuperSaiyan